# Clear internal app data on phone

Tags: flutter

I am using CachedNetworkImageProvider to store photos on the phone so I'm not having to go get them every time I load a screen.  But I want to program a way (button) that the user can clear the internal cache and it will go fetch all the images again.

Comment: Side note: The operating systems have a built-in ability to clear cache for specific applications, i.e. the operating systems Flutter builds for.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ImageCache/maximumSize.html

> Changes the maximum cache size.
>
> If the new size is smaller than the current number of elements, the
>   extraneous elements are evicted immediately. Setting this to zero and
>   then returning it to its original value will therefore immediately
>   clear the cache.

Comment: this isn't working for me, nor is the ImageCache.clear

Comment: Then it's probably best to create a bug report.